# Error When Trying To Submit EditText Form To My Email? No Apps Can Perform This Action?

Tags: java, android, email, android-studio, onclicklistener

Here is the Error Message...

> "Class 'Anonymous class derived from OnClickListener' must either be
>   declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onClick(View)' in
>   'OnClickListener'"

Here is the source code, anybody have an idea on how I can fix this error?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_donate);

    Button donationButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.donation_submit_button);
    donationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(DonateActivity.this, PostDonationActivity.class));
        }
    });


    donationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick() {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            i.setType("message/rfc822");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{
                    "ethan.reinsch@fillmorecentral.org"
            });
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Test Subject");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Test Body");
            try {
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(DonateActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

All help is very much appreciated!! I am fairly new to Android Studio, and Android App Development in General. Thank You!

UPDATE/EDIT:
I got it to work, but when I click submit, it says no apps can perform this action? I am using an emulator. Will it be different on an actual device? Thanks!

Comment: Why u have set OnClickListener twice on button

Comment: In second listener onClick method `View view` parameter is missing

Comment: After the user fills out the form, they hit the submit button. I need the submit button to send the form to my email, and take them to my "post_donation_page, which basically says "Thank You".

Comment: prosper k THANK YOU SO MUCH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
donationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       // here is problem
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            i.setType("message/rfc822");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{
                    "ethan.reinsch@fillmorecentral.org"
            });
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Test Subject");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Test Body");
            try {
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(DonateActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this, note SENDTO

```
   Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    i.setData(Uri.parse("mailto: " + EMAIL.getText().toString()));
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, editText.getText().toString());
   try {
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, ""));
```